# VSCode - wrap selected text in "<mark></mark>"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the markdown previewer in VSCode and would like the ability to highlight some text in an ".md" file and wrap it in a "`<mark></mark>`" tag so that it displays highlighted when you view the markdown file in its rendered format.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

A snippet should do the trick.

```
"wrap_mark": {
    "prefix": "wrap_mark",
    "body": [
        "<mark>$TM_SELECTED_TEXT</mark>"
    ],
    "description": "Wrap selected with <mark>"
},
```

Add that to your snippets/markdown.json file.

Then, add the following to your keybindings.json file

```
{ "key": "cmd+e 1", 
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", 
    "args": { "name": "wrap_mark" } 
},
```

Now, in your markdown file you can highlight the text and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>1</kbd> and the highlighted text gets wrapped in `<mark>`

[image]

I have a series of snippets mapped to <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> + "" - you can use any key combo you want (I'm on a Mac so I use the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key)

Answer (score 3):

In your user settings, add:

```
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [ ],
"emmet.includeLanguages": {"markdown": "html"},
```

This enables emmet in markdown files.

Then in the markdown file, use the `Emmet: Wrap with abbreviation` command:

[image]

You can also [create a snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) that does this specifically for `<mark/>`. Take a look at the `TM_SELECTED_TEXT` snippet variable